# Calculation Errors when using Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, invalid-argument

I have developed an app with Ruby on Rails, which is uses Sidekiq to run queries in parallel.
The user can:

- submit queries (which are models also), each of which can have one or
  more entities. The queue is handled by Sidekiq.

  **OR**
- create the entity, and call the function that does the calculation
  directly (which is less practical when you have 100s of entities).

CalculationJob is a model that I created to handle caclulations for each entity. When the calculation is done, CalculationResults are made and save in a database. Every entity has_one calculationResults

When I use either method to process only one entity, calculations are done correctly. However, when I submit one or more queries, which are handled by Sidekiq,
 I experience two problems

a) it happens that sometimes, the validation of an entity fails. I would get error messages like this one:

Job            Arguments           Error

CalculationJob ***/Entity/123:     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: name can't be blank, name is invalid

Surprisingly, if I use the console to locate the entity (via the aformentioned id), I find that one was created with the right attributes

b) Sometimes the calculation for some specific entities will be wrong. If delete the saved calculation results and try one more time from the console, I get the correct result.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issues? What could be the problem here?

Thank you

Thank you in advance,

Yannick

Comment: Hard to say, not seeing any code.

Comment: You are right. Well, I have partly figured out the problem. The CalculationJob(Entity) creates objects as part of the process, and these objects are associated with the Entity. I found that sometimes, the creation of the object fails, even when it should not. The job is then put back in the queue for another try, and then eventually succeeds. This only occurs there are many other ClassificationJobs waiting in the queue. So I guess it has to do with sidekiq.  \n Has anyone had such a problem before?